# how to make a nautilus context menu script to play media files in local LCD TV

Tags: nautilus, multimedia, mediaserver, dlna, upnp

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 32 bit OS and Sony Bravia LCD TV. I want to play media files through LAN. I tried many UPNP servers but none of them provide an easy way to play media files in smart tv. Actually I only managed to work **ushare**.
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There two solutions.

1. the simplies is to use a control point like http://www.eezupnp.de/
   With this control point you can play both files from media server like ushare and also from the hard disk directly
2. The other solution is to use nautilus context menu plugin from Coherence-Nautilus-Send file for playback This one is a little more complicated since the script that is on the web page is not working with mu Ubuntu 14.04. So here what has to be done:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install python-nautilus python-coherence`

The plugin uses DBus to communicate with a Coherence instance.
To have a Coherence ControlPoint instance started automatically by the DBus daemon, download the file service file and copy/save it to 
/usr/share/dbus-1/services

```
sudo wget http://coherence.beebits.net/browser/trunk/Coherence/misc/org.Coherence.service -o /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.Coherence.service
```

Then download the plugin script [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_BwIrwQDLdxZmlsNHc1eW0wSUE/view) and save it to /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions (as root)

After that restart the system. After reboot plugin should be runing. Open a folder with some videos, mouse right click on a file, context menu should be shown with "play with >" item.

If it is not working then try to restart nautilus. 
open terminal CTRL+ALT+t

```
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

should show

> CoherencePlayExtension pid

If not then try to start coherence manualy in terminal

```
coherence -o use_dbus:yes -o controlpoint:yes
```